# Swift: Understanding // MARK

Tags: xcode, swift, comments

What is the purpose of writing comments in Swift as:

```c
// MARK: This is a comment
```

When you can also do:

```c
// This is a comment
```

What does the `// MARK` achieve?

Answer (score 397, accepted):

The `// MARK:` and `// MARK: -` syntax in Swift functions identically to the `#pragma mark` and `#pragma mark -` syntax in Objective-C.

When using this syntax (plus `// TODO:` and `// FIXME:`), you can get some extra information to show up in the quick jump bar.

Consider these few lines of source code:

```
// MARK: A mark comment lives here.

func isPrime(_ value: UInt) -> Bool { return true }
```

[image]

And for reference, the quick jump bar is at the top in Xcode:

[image]

It exists mostly to help with quick navigation within the file.

Note that the dash (`// MARK: -`) causes a nice separation line to show up.  Consider this `MARK` comment:

```
// MARK: - A mark comment lives here.
```

[image]

The darker gray separator line just above the bolded option in that menu comes from the dash.

Additionally, we can achieve this separator line without a comment by simply not having any text after the dash:

```
// MARK: -
```

[image]

As mentioned, `// TODO:` and `// FIXME:` comments will also appear here.

```
// MARK: - Prime functions

func isPrime(_ value: UInt) -> Bool {
    // TODO: Actually implement the logic for this method
    return true
}

func nthPrime(_ value: UInt) -> Int {
    // FIXME: Returns incorrect values for some arguments
    return 2
}
```

[image]

- FIXMEs get a little band-aid icon that help them standout.
- MARK icon looks like a table of contents
- TODO icons look more like a checklist

Clicking on any line in the quick jump bar takes you directly to that line in the source code.

Comment: Is this functionality specific to Swift/Objective-C or Xcode?

Comment: Xcode, presumably.  Although, I can easily imagine that other IDEs will potentially exhibit similar behavior.

Comment: You can also put the hyphen after your text, `// MARK: /Delegate impl. -`, to mark the end of a section, or why not both: `// MARK: - Attention! -`

Comment: @Andreas hyphen `-` is just a horizontal line. No any additional mark presents the meaning of **the end of section**.

Comment: @ooops Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Yes, it's a horizontal line.

Comment: when should I use `///` vs `//` in project? All the Apple's documentation is in `///`

Comment: `///` turns your comment into doc comments that can show up when that code is called or if you generate doc comments for your Swift code.

Comment: It should be noted that the //MARK comments show up on the minimap

Answer (score 16):

MARK simply adds a visual MARK in the jump bar like this:

ex `// MARK: Core Data Stack`

[image]